# Post method is not working online

Tags: php, post

I want to input some data through PHP MySQL. so I have written a form, some method in a class and a controller to process the whole thing, It is working fine with localhost, data are inserted according to programming logic, but in online form post method is not working. No data is sent to controller page. I am feeling helpless with the problem.
the is given bellow.

```
 <form method="post" action="registrationcontroller.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" required/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your phone" required/><br/>
    <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" required/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="callsign"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your call sign if any" ><br/>
    <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your location" required/><br/>
    <textarea name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your full address"></textarea> <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add">
</form>
```

this is my controller code

```
require_once 'Registrationclass.php';
$registration = new Registrationclass();

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{

    if(isset($_POST["name"])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }   
    if(isset($_POST["phone"])){
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    }   
    if(isset($_POST["email"])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } 

    if(isset($_POST["location"])){
        $location = $_POST['location'];
    } 
    if(isset($_POST["callsign"])){
        $callsign = $_POST['callsign'];  
    } 
    if($callsign=="") {
        $callsign="SWL";
    }
    if(isset($_POST["address"])){
        $address = $_POST['address'];
    } 
}
$registration->setName($name);  
$registration->setEmail($email);
$registration->setPhone($phone);
$registration->setLocation($location);
$registration->setAddress($address);
$registration->setCallsign($callsign);
$registration->setStatus("Pending");

$registrationid= "JCBIARF-".rand(1000,3000); 
$registration->setRegistrationid($registrationid); 
$registration->adduser();
$registration->redirect("registration.php?regsuc=true");
```

please help to resolve the problem.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: there is no error, offline it is ok, all the data are inserted in database, online just print or echo $_POST['var'] shows nothing.

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very beginning of your php script and see what errors come up.